# Flask dynamic models

Tags: flask, model

I want to know if it's possible to have a variable for models ?

```
 table = 'Cms'
 query = table.query

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'query'
```

Answer (score 0):

The table name is set automatically for you if you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy, and if you are trying to override the table name, try looking up '**tablename**' class attribute.

Ps: I need a little more context to understand what you're trying to do here though.